# How do Biblical Unitarians interpret Malachi 3:1-5?

Tags: exegesis, christology, unitarianism, malachi, biblical-unitarian

Malachi 3:1-5 (ESV):

> “Behold, **I send** my messenger, and he will prepare the way **before me**. And **the Lord whom you seek will suddenly come to his temple**; and **the messenger of the covenant** in whom you delight, behold, he is coming, **says the LORD of hosts**. 2 But who can endure the day of his coming, and who can stand when he appears? For he is like a refiner's fire and like fullers' soap. 3 He will sit as a refiner and purifier of silver, and he will purify the sons of Levi and refine them like gold and silver, and they will bring offerings in righteousness to the LORD. 4 Then the offering of Judah and Jerusalem will be pleasing to the LORD as in the days of old and as in former years.
>
> 5 “Then I will draw near to you for judgment. I will be a swift witness against the sorcerers, against the adulterers, against those who swear falsely, against those who oppress the hired worker in his wages, the widow and the fatherless, against those who thrust aside the sojourner, and do not fear me, says the LORD of hosts.

Trinitarians usually interpret Malachi 3:1-5 as evidence that Jesus is Jehovah, by picking up on the fact that Jehovah is speaking in the first person about himself, but then it turns out that the one who came was Jesus. For more details, here are [two](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/56076/38524) [examples](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/56079/38524) of this kind of exegesis on the passage, taken from the hermeneutics site. Of course, this way of exegeting Malachi 3:1-5 totally contradicts the Christological views of Biblical Unitarians.

How do Biblical Unitarians exegete Malachi 3:1-5?

Comment: "it turns out that the one who came was Jesus" I find this passage quite vague. Can you say a bit more explicitly what you think the problem is here for Biblical Unitarians? Is it that a typical interpretation is 'Lord' = God, but 'messenger of the covenant' = Jesus, but also 'Lord' = 'messenger of the covenant', so therefore 'Jesus' = 'God'?

Comment: @OneGodtheFather - yes, exactly. See Dottard's answer [here](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/56079/38524) to see the idea developed more in detail. But here is an excerpt: *“Behold, I [YHWH = Jesus] will send My messenger [John the Baptist], who will prepare the way before Me [Jesus]. Then the Lord [Jesus] whom you seek will suddenly come to His [Jesus'] temple—the Messenger of the covenant [Jesus], in whom you delight—see, He is coming,” says the LORD of Hosts [pre-incarnate Jesus]*.

Comment: [This similar question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/78195/23657) may be helpful